# Can't reload supervisor with supervisorctl 'reload' command

Tags: supervisord

I'm running `supervisord` on my CentOS 6 box like so,

```
/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

and when I launch `supervisorctl` all process status are fine,
but if I try the `reload` command in supervisorctl, and then do anything, I get

> unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock no such file

but the reload command should take care of recreating the .sock?

I'm using the same config file I've used successfully on other boxes, and im running everything as root. I can't undesrtand what the problem is...

**Config file:**

```
; Sample supervisor config file.

[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
;chmod=0700                 ; socket file mode (default 0700)
;chown=nobody:nogroup       ; socket file uid:gid owner
;username=user              ; (default is no username (open server))
;password=123               ; (default is no password (open server))

;[inet_http_server]         ; inet (TCP) server disabled by default
;port=127.0.0.1:9001        ; (ip_address:port specifier, *:port for all iface)
;username=user              ; (default is no username (open server))
;password=123               ; (default is no password (open server))

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
;umask=022                   ; (process file creation umask;default 022)
;user=chrism                 ; (default is current user, required if root)
;identifier=supervisor       ; (supervisord identifier, default is 'supervisor')
;directory=/tmp              ; (default is not to cd during start)
;nocleanup=true              ; (don't clean up tempfiles at start;default false)
;childlogdir=/tmp            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
;environment=KEY=value       ; (key value pairs to add to environment)
;strip_ansi=false            ; (strip ansi escape codes in logs; def. false)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
;serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001 ; use an http:// url to specify an inet socket
;username=chris              ; should be same as http_username if set
;password=123                ; should be same as http_password if set
;prompt=mysupervisor         ; cmd line prompt (default "supervisor")
;history_file=~/.sc_history  ; use readline history if available

; The below sample program section shows all possible program subsection values,
; create one or more 'real' program: sections to be able to control them under
; supervisor.

;[program:foo]
;command=/bin/cat

[program:embed_scheduler]
command=/opt/web-apps/mywebsite/custom_process.py
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)d
numprocs=3

;[program:theprogramname]
;command=/bin/cat              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
;process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
;numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
;directory=/tmp                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
;autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
;autorestart=unexpected        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
;startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=QUIT               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;killasgroup=false             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
;user=chrism                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
;stdout_logfile=/a/path        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
;stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
;stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
;stderr_logfile=/a/path        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
;stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
;stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A=1,B=2           ; process environment additions (def no adds)
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)

; The below sample eventlistener section shows all possible
; eventlistener subsection values, create one or more 'real'
; eventlistener: sections to be able to handle event notifications
; sent by supervisor.


;[eventlistener:theeventlistenername]
;command=/bin/eventlistener    ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
;process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
;numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1)
;events=EVENT                  ; event notif. types to subscribe to (req'd)
;buffer_size=10                ; event buffer queue size (default 10)
;directory=/tmp                ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
;umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
;priority=-1                   ; the relative start priority (default -1)
;autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
;autorestart=unexpected        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
;startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
;startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
;exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
;stopsignal=QUIT               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
;stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
;killasgroup=false             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
;user=chrism                   ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
;redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
;stdout_logfile=/a/path        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
;stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
;stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
;stderr_logfile=/a/path        ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
;stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
;stderr_logfile_backups        ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
;stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
;environment=A=1,B=2           ; process environment additions
;serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)

; The below sample group section shows all possible group values,
; create one or more 'real' group: sections to create "heterogeneous"
; process groups.

;[group:thegroupname]
;programs=progname1,progname2  ; each refers to 'x' in [program:x] definitions
;priority=999                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

;[include]
;files = relative/directory/*.ini
```

Comment: Did you check /tmp/supervisor.sock exists immediately before using supervisorctl, and that supervisord has not already exited and removed it?

Comment: ramruma- that's what doesn't make sense. I'm IN supervisorctl and call 'reload', so that command should handle recreating the .sock file

Comment: I have the same problem. It's not doing what it's meant to do! If you just run supervisord it should boot the daemon then ctl should work.

Answer (score 4):

This is a supervisord bug: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/121#issuecomment-11445156

I've worked around it by reverting to v3.0a10.

Comment: I had these weird issues using the version of supervisord in the CentOS yum repos.  Nuked that version & went with the easy_install method.  No problem since.  The version in the repos is pretty old too & doesn't support a lot of the new features on their website.

Answer (score 2):

they solved the bug in the latest release (3.0b2, 2013-05-28)

> Reverted a change to logging introduced in 3.0b1 that was intended to
>   allow multiple processes to log to the same file with the rotating log
>   handler. The implementation caused supervisord to crash during reload
>   and to leak file handles. Also, since log rotation options are given
>   on a per-program basis, impossible configurations could be created
>   (conflicting rotation options for the same file). Given this and that
>   supervisord now has syslog support, it was decided to remove this
>   feature. A warning was added to the documentation that two processes
>   may not log to the same file.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor

https://pypi.crate.io/packages/source/s/supervisor/supervisor-3.0b2.tar.gz#md5=e2557853239ee69955f993091b0eddc4

Just tested and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sock file is right in supervisor configuration. 
`sudo nano /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`

check my answer in other post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/808732/supervisor-sock-file-missing/1008453#1008453)